# Не запускается Linux после добавления оперативной памяти

Tags: linux, ram

У меня есть ноутбук который поддерживает ddr2 память у меня стояло 2 Гб (C 2мя планками всё запускалось и работало) памяти и я вставил ещё одну плашку на 2 ГБ суммарно Получилось четыре пробовал запустить Linux это Ubuntu 22.04 лтс и он не запускается пробовал запустить Windows 10 на другом жёстком диске и она запускается и прекрасно работает В чём это может быть проблемы и как мне это запустить на линуксе чтобы это всё работало (как исправить)?
Процессор Intel Pentium t3200 Dual Core ноутбук Samsung r410 Plus

Comment: не совсем понятно, у вас Ubuntu 22.04 на 2 гигах до этого на этом ноутбуке запускалась - загружался установочный образ, установка на диск, запуск с диска ? и тока после добавления еще 2 гига перестал запускаться установочный образа и/или запуск с диска на котором установлен ?

Comment: Да, всё так и есть

Comment: Странно что то, линукс вообще может работать везде на любой "железке" и отлично переносится...

Comment: Что мне делать, винду устанавливать не хочется.

Comment: Может там в файлах системы пункт с загрузкой есть? Который позволяет устанавливать загрузочную память. Live CD тоже не загружается. То есть у меня с 2мя планками работает только windows, а linux работать не хочет.

Comment: попробуйте загрузить предыдущий(20.04) загрузочный образ убунты, ну или еще как вариант сбросить настройки биоса, может поможет

Comment: Сброс настроек BIOSа не помог, и кстати я пробовал запустить Ubuntu 16.04. Она тоже не работает. Поэтому думаю нет смысла пробовать запускать Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: https://www.memtest86.com/

Comment: Memtest++ говорит что всё OK

Comment: Система при загрузки Ubuntu уходит в перезапуск. Планки менять местами пробовал, не помогает

Comment: [Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145512/discussion-between-mine-fine-and-aepot)

Comment: гляньте [этот вопрос](https://qna.habr.com/q/32525) на тостере, если кратко, то ставьте либо 32-битный linux, ну либо 64-битный но нужно будет указать ядру при загрузке mem=4096m (но будет видеть 3 гига). Кстати, под виндой он видит все 4 гига или меньше ?